# Not sure where some of my transaction went

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, electrum, replace-by-fee

I just made a transaction of 61.80 Euros, but it charged me 88.01, And I'm not sure why.

Some background: I'm using a service called HodlHodl to turn my mined bitcoin into money. I use Electrum as my wallet.

This is the transaction, if it helps:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0cf8e157f7783bd3a8ea92f17fe4c4d5193b69241b950c13d3e9b5a7fbaed68b

The part I'm unsure about are the other 2 outputs, besides the 61.80 Euro one. Would be very thankful for the 24.72 Euro output to be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. I found out that it is a 2 factor authentication fee. At first I just didn't expect it to be this much.